# Detect right and left shift keys pressed together from within Awesome WM

Tags: shortcut-keys, awesome

I want to have Awesome WM run a command when both Shift keys (left and right) are pressed together.

I know Linux can differentiate between the two shift keys (e.g., one can tell Gnome to change the keyboard layout when both Shift keys are pressed together).

Is there a way to do this in Awesome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my computer, it ended up working with the following:

```
  awful.key({ "Shift", }, "Shift_R", function () somefunction() end),
```

`Shift_L` does not seem to be recognized.  But `Shift` + `Shift_R` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Shift_R` and `Shift_L` instead of just `Shift` for this.

```
...
awful.key({ modkey, "Shift_R"   }, "Shift_L", function () awful.client.swap.byidx(  1)    end),
...
```